# Quick sort imlpementation in Java-wrong output

Tags: java, quicksort

I am trying to implement quick sort using Java.The partition function does what it should do.That is,partition the array around the pivot(I've chosen the element as the pivot). But the final output is not in sorted order.I cannot figure the error out.Can someone help?

```
public class Quick_sort {


    public static int arr[] = {11, 2, 7, 1, 5, 4, 12, 65, 23};
    public static int temp = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int p=0;
        int r=arr.length;

        quick_sort(p,r);        

        for(int i: arr)
            System.out.println(i);
    }


    public static int partition(int p, int r) {
        if(p < r) {
            int pivot=arr[p];
            int i=1;

            for(int j=1;j<r;j++) {
                if(arr[j]<pivot) {
                    temp=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=temp;
                    i++;
                }
            }

            temp=arr[i-1];
            arr[i-1]=arr[p];
            arr[p]=temp;
            for(int m=0;m<r;m++) {
                if(arr[m]==pivot) {
                    temp=m;
                }
            }
        }
        return temp;    
    }

    public static void quick_sort(int p,int r) {
        if(p>=r) return;
        int index=partition(p,r);
        quick_sort(p,index-1);
        quick_sort(index+1,r-1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: http://java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/quick-sort/, http://java67.blogspot.in/2014/07/quicksort-algorithm-in-java-in-place-example.html, http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/quicksort-algorithm-in-java-code-example/ Go through with this link.

Comment: Your code wasn't indented and you didn't mention where exactly you were facing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for not indenting the program.The problem is this:When I just print the array after passing it to partition method,the output is as it should be.That is,the elements smaller than the pivot come before it and those greater than it come after it.But when it recurse using quick_sort(p,index-1) and quick_sort(index+1,r-1),the output is not in sorted order.(index is the index of the pivot after partitioning).

Answer (score 0):

In your last line

```
quick_sort(index+1,r-1);
```

You skip the last element of the array. But the last element should be sorted as well. Try it with:

```
 quick_sort(index+1,r);
```

And it is better to adapt the variables i and j in the partition method to the current processed part of the array.

Comment: How does the current output look like?

Comment: input: { 25,3,7,5,1,0,22,43,29,10,13 } (I changed the input after posting the question). Output: 25, 3, 7, 5, 1, 0, 22, 43, 29, 10, 13

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to fix it. Try it with (main function):

```
int r=arr.length-1;
```

and change the partition function to:

```
public static int partition(int p, int r) {
    if(p < r) {
        int pivot=arr[p];
        int i= p ;

        for(int j=(p+1);j<=r;j++) {
            if(arr[j]<pivot) {
                temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                i++;
            }
        }
        temp = i;
    }
    return temp;    
}
```

as well as the in the quick-sort method:

```
quick_sort(p,index-1);
quick_sort(index+1,r);
```

Do you see your problem? Your main problem was to not adapt the variables to the smaller parts you are actually looking at at the moment. It did well for the first partition round, but not for the following, as you had the former variables.

Answer (score -1):

This is a complete example of a **QuickSort** implementation :

```
public class QuickSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 9, 2, 4, 7, 3, 7, 10 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));

        int low = 0;
        int high = x.length - 1;

        quickSort(x, low, high);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return;

        if (low >= high)
            return;

        // pick the pivot
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = arr[middle];

        // make left < pivot and right > pivot
        int i = low, j = high;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }

            while (arr[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        // recursively sort two sub parts
        if (low < j)
            quickSort(arr, low, j);

        if (high > i)
            quickSort(arr, i, high);
    }
}
```

you can find more [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/11/quicksort-array-in-java/).

Comment: What is the problem with the actual code asked about?

Comment: Indent your code if you want help ! .. thks for the minus :)

Comment: Ah sorry !  Prashant Pandey should intend his code .. Have a nice day :)